# Containing Hide/Show DIV Hides on mouseover of Google+ Follow Button

Tags: jquery, html, google-plus, jquery-hover

I am working on a hover drop-down panel, containing the Google+, Facebook, Youtube, and Twitter social widgets listed for visitors to "one-click" each of them without the panel closing.

I started with simple jquery drop-down menu, simplified it down to a single ul li div, so on mouseover of a single menu item (Socialize), it displays a div containing all 4 social widgets. So far so good. as long as you hover over the single menu item or the div that contains the 4 social widgets, it remains visible, and moving outside the div causes it to hide.

The issue I am having, is that the Google+ widget has a Follow button, which on mouseover, opens it's own small drop menu to select which circle you wish to choose. when this Google+ drop menu appears, the parent div loses "focus" for lack of a better term, and the containing div hides. I have tried to drill down into the Google+ widget and hand pick some of the divs to add to my simple jquery drop-down script with no luck.

Does anyone know how I can keep the containing div open when the Google+ widget Follow button is hovered?

Here is my simple jquery.

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.dropdown li').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('left', '-200px');
        //$('ul:first',this).css('display', 'block');

    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('left', '-2000px');
        //$('ul:first',this).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

The two lines that are commented out were the original Hide/Show, but due to issues with the widgets not loading properly in a hidden div, I opted to keep it visible and simply shuffle it off the side of the viewport. whole sperarate issue. I simply need to resolve the Google+ Follow Button mouseover causing parent DIV to disappear.

Edit: Here is the site for further clarification.
http://www.lawncaremarketingexpert.com/

Comment: Bump. I am still looking for a solution to this problem. the only solution given so far is to add the jquery show div to the google+ widget's drop down menu to keep the parent div visible, but this is not a solution as I do not know the selector name of the div in the google+ widget. Can anyone offer a working solution? I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Almost a year later and I still have no answer to this question. Still using this drop menu and would really like to solve this issue. maybe a better solution would be to have a hot zone around the drop menu that triggers the collapse of the menu on mouse out. I realize this could accidentally stay open if someone were to mouse out fast enough, but I could make the hot zone around the menu extra large to help prevent this. Can anyone point me to a good (and simple) drop menu example that stays visible until an outer area is moused over? Or a solution to the original problem of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'event.stopPropagation()' inside the Google+ div's mouseover event. Something like this:

```
$('<Google+ div selector>').mouseover(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Workaround:

```
$('<Google+ div selector>').mouseover(function(e){
     jQuery('<parent dropdown panel selector>').show();
  });
```

Comment: I tried this using a handful of selectors I dug out of the Google+ widget with no luck. I am shooting in the dark since I can't find the exact selector.

Comment: I suspect your autoplay() function with the setInterval has something to do with this. You may need to debug. @Allan

Comment: I do not know the Google+ div selector. if you know what it is, or how to locate it via jquery, please enlighten me. I understand your solution, but it solves nothing without the actual selector, and that's what I can't find. Your Workaround is what I tried to do initially, before posting here for assistance. I assumed it was because I could not find the correct selector or due to the complicated structure of the Google+ widget. You seem to be suggesting that I am actually finding it, but it is not working due to the jquery included in the page for the slider.